# django-filtering manytomanyfield value_list

Tags: django-queryset, manytomanyfield

```
views.py:      

def User_gek(request):
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            user_list = MYOBJECT.objects.values('users') #or values_list
            #print user_list

            for x in User:
              if query:
                if query.lower() in x.lower():
                    in_filter.append(x)

        if query:
            user_list = user_list.filter(
                Q(users__in=in_filter)
            ).distinct()
models.py
class MYOBJECT(models.Model):
 users= models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I try to get User's from users. but when I run this code I got this error:
'ModelBase' object is not iterable

Traceback:  --> for stories in User:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `for x in User:`.
`User` is a model and you're trying to iterate over a class basically. I think what you meant to do is `for x in User.objects.all()` that returns a queryset of every user in the database.